# Cheapest way to "isolate" sub-circuits for partial power-down?

Tags: multiplexer, low-power, circuit-protection

My design is extremely power-consumption sensitive, and I need to power parts of design down (using load switches) when they are not in use. I need a way to prevent myself from unintentionally back-driving I/O pins across the power domains – including both low-speed IO and higher-speed buses like SPI. What component options/techniques do people like for this type of application? I'm currently considering analog muxes and level shifters with "partial power-down protection" – but given the cost of these, I'm guessing I'm missing other fundamental options.

Comment: It depend a lot what submodules they are and how they connect to your MCU. You don't need any analog muxes or level shifters, if you configure MCU pins appropriately.

Comment: Do you have bidirectional signals too, or only unidirectional stuff? (For example, SPI has only unidirectional signals, while I2C has bidirectional ones)

Comment: Read about "cold sparing".

Comment: @Justme Yeah – I could just configure everything as high-Z before I power down, I guess.

Comment: @JonathanS. Both unidirectional and bidirectional.

Comment: @Mattman944 Very useful search term; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is no specific reason to add any components (and you gave none), you can simply set all outputs to low, and any inputs that have pull-ups enabled can just be turned on as inputs without pull-ups. Or inputs with pull-down, if possible or necessary.

Of course segmeting the design also means that you must carefully assess where any external pull-up resistors should be, either on the turned-off supply, or on the remaining supply.

Answer (score 0):

This question was a little too vague, and I think I can answer it myself. With uni- and bi-directional signals, there are a lot of options to deal with segmentation of the power domain – including the following:

- Configuration of the MCU pins to high-impedance, prior to power-down using the load switch.
- Use of low-cost non-inverting buffers with support for partial power-down.
- Use of level shifters with support for partial power down where level-shifting is relevant.
- Use of analog muxes where absolutely necessary, or for higher-speed signals.